# Change canvas property for an Item

Tags: plsql, oracleforms

Is it possible to set canvas property of an item programmatically? For example, I set canvas property of TextItem to cnv1. When I open cnv2 I want TextItem to appear on it.

Comment: No, you can't. You need to create one item on CNV1 and another on CNV2 and set the same value on both items or use the "Synchronize with Item" property on the second item

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was afraid of.